# How can I verify the BTC supply with my own node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, money-supply

With all the supply talk going on I wanted to verify the active supply on my new node I got. What is the best way to "run the numbers" I am running a raspiblitz node.

Answer (score 4):

To verify the supply, you have to compute the theoretical maximum issuance based on the block subsidy schedule. Then you can use the `gettxoutsetinfo` RPC which will output the total amount of Bitcoin in the UTXO set in a field named `total_amount`. Lastly you check that the amount in the UTXO set is less than or equal to the theoretical maximum issuance.

Comment: Thanks. I am running a raspberry pi 4 and this seems to always time out when I  try gettxoutsetinfo. Is there any guidance and what i should try differently?

Comment: You can remove the `bitcoin-cli` timeout by using `-rpcclienttimeout=0` option.

Comment: Thanks having issues with that... trying bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=password -rpcclienttimeout=0 

Getting too few params ( need at least command ).

Comment: You still need to have `gettxoutsetinfo` in your `bitcoin-cli` command. So you would have something like `bitcoin-cli -rpcclienttimeout=0 gettxoutsetinfo` (rpcuser and rpcpassword usually aren't required, `bitcoin-cli` reads them from the datadir).