# Get the historic circulated suppy

Tags: supply

I'm looking for the historic circulated supply of Bitcoin.  I'm aware I can get the current supply by creating my own node.  But I need the supply at a given date.

Does anyone know of an API to get it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I verify the BTC supply with my own node?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98584/how-can-i-verify-the-btc-supply-with-my-own-node)

Comment: @Saxtheowl No, I can find the current supply, I need the historic suppy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `gettxoutsetinfo` will return the current supply in `total_amount` so it doesn't help. `getblockstats` doesn't return supply info for the block.
2. [Bitcoinvisuals](https://bitcoinvisuals.com/chain-supply) has the supply chart and you can move the cursor over the chart to know supply at any given date in past.

[image: supply]

3. Since we know block rewards (new coins added to supply) and they are reduced to half after every 210,000 blocks, we can also write a simple script to know the supply at any given block:

```
def btcSupplyAtBlock(b):
    if b >= 33 * 210000:
        return 20999999.9769
    else:
        reward = 50e8
        supply = 0
        y = 210000  
        while b > y - 1:
            supply = supply + y * reward
            reward = int(reward / 2.0)
            b = b - y
        supply = supply + b * reward
        return (supply + reward) / 1e8


if __name__ == "__main__":
    block = 1000000
    print(btcSupplyAtBlock(block))
```

<sup>Source: https://github.com/ndsvw/Bitcoin-Supply-Calculator</sup>

4. There are lot of third party APIs available like coinmetrics to achieve the same.

In `3` the script will not include lot of exceptions mentioned in this answer by *sipa*: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/38998/

Comment: Thank you so much this is very detailed and gives me a lot of options